# I want to make a stacked bar graph which has target of 60 using chart js

Tags: javascript, php, html, chart.js

I want to create a bar chart using chartjs which will show how much more needed to achieve 60 which will be shown in red bar above. Below will show the current amount in blue. Let's say I have to achieve 60 and the current value is 40, bar chart should show in red that 20 more is required to achieve 60. If it achieves 60, there should not be any red bar above. Is there a way to do this?

```
(function() {


 var ctx = document.getElementById("mychart");

  var datas = {
    labels: ['Passed', 'Failed', 'In Progress'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Data',
      data: [10, 5, 80],
      backgroundColor: [
        "green",
        "red",
        "yellow"
      ],
    }, ]
  };

  


  var chr = new Chart(ctx, {
    data: datas,
    type: 'bar'
  });


})();

<div style="width: 500px;height: 300px">
  <canvas id="mychart"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can simply calculate this before sending it to chart.js to chart it:

```js
(function() {
  const ctx = document.getElementById("mychart");

  const datas = {
    labels: ['Passed', 'Failed', 'In Progress'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Data',
      data: [10, 5, 80],
      backgroundColor: [
        "green",
        "red",
        "yellow"
      ],
    }, ]
  };

  const newData = datas.datasets[0].data.map(e => (e >= 60 ? 0 : 60 - e))

  datas.datasets.push({
    label: 'extra',
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    data: newData
  })

  const chr = new Chart(ctx, {
    data: datas,
    type: 'bar'
  });
})();

<div style="width: 500px;height: 300px">
  <canvas id="mychart"></canvas>
</div>
```